# conditionally assign docvar()

Tags: r, quanteda

I am using `quanteda` and want to conditionally assign `docvars()`.

Consider the following MWE:

```
library(dplyr)
library(quanteda)
library(quanteda.corpora)

testcorp <- corpus(data_corpus_movies))
```

I now want to assign a dummy docvar `neg_sent_lg_id2`, which should be `1` for all documents where the `Sentiment` is `neg` *and* where the `id2` is `> 10000`.

Importantly, *I don't want to subset* the corpus but **I want to assign the docvar to a subset of the corpus and then retain the entire corpus**.

I have used `docvars(testcorp, field = "neg_sent_lg_id2") <- 0` to assign 0 to the docvars and would now like to do something like this - the following lines are pseudo `r` code and do not work but convey the idea.

```
corpus_subset(testcorp, Sentiment == "neg") %>% # filter on "Sentiment"
    corpus_subset(testcorp, id2 > 10000) %>% # filter on "id2"
    docvars(testcorp, field = "neg_sent_lg_id2") <- 1 # selectively assign docvar
```

Comment: I don't understand this bit: `corpus_subset(testcorp, id2 > 10000)`. Why do you first want to subset the corpus? It does not seem necessary or even possible for what you are doing as all docs need to have the same docvars afaik.

Comment: that line was only to write (in pseudo-code) what I wanted to achieve.

Comment: Ok great. FYI, the way you are using the pipe above is not correct. It should be `%>% corpus_subset(id2 > 10000)` as the point of the pipe is to leave out the first argument (usually the data).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ifelse` for this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(quanteda)
library(quanteda.corpora)

testcorp <- corpus(data_corpus_movies)

docvars(testcorp, field = "neg_sent_lg_id2") <- 
  ifelse(docvars(testcorp, field = "Sentiment") == "neg" & docvars(testcorp, field = "id2") > 10000,
         1, 0)
```

It's not a pretty syntax but it works:

```r
head(docvars(testcorp))
#>                 Sentiment   id1   id2 neg_sent_lg_id2
#> neg_cv000_29416       neg cv000 29416               1
#> neg_cv001_19502       neg cv001 19502               1
#> neg_cv002_17424       neg cv002 17424               1
#> neg_cv003_12683       neg cv003 12683               1
#> neg_cv004_12641       neg cv004 12641               1
#> neg_cv005_29357       neg cv005 29357               1
table(docvars(testcorp, field = "neg_sent_lg_id2"))
#> 
#>    0    1 
#> 1005  995
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>